# how to set folder ACLs from C#

Tags: c#, acl, ntfs

How can I automate the following manual steps in C#?

- Right click a folder in Windows Explorer;

  `Properties -> Security -> Advanced -> Edit`
- Un-tick "Include inheritable permissions from this object's parent" and click Remove.
- Click Add, choose a group and grant it Modify rights.

I've found [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/cumpsd/archive/2004/02/08/69403.aspx), which looks like exactly what i need, but I don't have and cant find `Microsoft.Win32.Security`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

check the code below:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strFullPath);

DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();

//check off & copy inherited security setting 
dSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true); 

dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.objectsecurity.setaccessruleprotection.aspx

and this for setting permissions on a folder :

http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about that one, but you should be able to do that via the [DirectorySecurity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.directorysecurity.aspx) class in the `System.Security.AccessControl` namespace.

And I assume you'd probably want to look at the [InheritanceFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.accesscontrol.inheritanceflags.aspx) enumeration as well.

Comment: @Andrew: No problem, Aneef obviously put more effort into his to make it a more comprehensive answer so makes sense that his is accepted.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that ACLs are not part of .Net Standard as of 2.0, however, if you install via:

Install-Package Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility -Version 2.0.1
   Install-Package Microsoft.DotNet.Analyzers.Compatibility -Version 0.2.12-alpha

You will get extensions methods matching what you are accustomed to in full .Net Framework.  For example, I need to set directory security, after installing the above, this code compiles with warnings that some of the methods are not available on linux or macOS

```
 DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(strFullPath);
 DirectorySecurity dSecurity = dInfo.GetAccessControl();
 //check off & copy inherited security setting 
 dSecurity.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true); 
 dInfo.SetAccessControl(dSecurity);
```

for more information, see https://github.com/dotnet/docs/blob/master/docs/core/porting/windows-compat-pack.md