# How to change directory security of the default website in iis6.0 through .net code

Tags: .net, authentication, iis-6

I need to configure the IIS through the .net code and one of the steps is to change the directory security (anonymous and authentication methods) of the default website of the iis from the .net code. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: What kind of security do you want to set? Filesystem ACLs or authorization?

Comment: I want to edit anonymous and authentication methods of the default website

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626361/how-to-set-folder-acls-from-c-sharp